# Deleting Root Node From BST

Tags: search, tree, binary, binary-search-tree

[I am trying to figure out how to delete root node from this BST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38ZpW.png)

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the values of the root with the values of either its predecessor (the maximum value in the left sub-tree) or its successor (the minimum value in the right sub-tree). Once that is done, you perform a delete on the swapped node.

So this would look like this if you used predecessor:

1. Swap 8 and 9 in the tree
2. Delete the node that now contains 9

Note: in the future, please try to do your due diligence in terms of researching your question before posting it here. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/) is a simple answer to your question.